# JSTL c:when xml string test

Tags: jsp, jstl, jsp-tags

So I have a stream of xml that I am rendering on my jsp page.

For the sake of this example the string needing testing would be displayed as:

```
<x:out select="$xmlStream/TITLE" />
```

I need to test that string:

```
<c:when test="${TITLE == 'x'}">
```

But I am not sure of the correct syntax for the test...
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<c:set var="title">
    <x:out select="$xmlStream/TITLE" />
</c:set>

<c:if test="${title == 'x'}"/>  
   ---your code---
</c:if>
```

Comment: Yep. That is what I needed. Thanks.